# Does "for" in .Net Framework 4.0 execute loops in parallel? Or why is the total not the sum of the parts

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am writing code to performance test a web site. I have the following code:

```
        string url = "http://xxxxxx";
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch totalTime = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        totalTime.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            webResponse.Close();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            textBox1.Text += "Time Taken " + i.ToString() + " = " + stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            stopwatch.Reset();

        }

        totalTime.Stop();
        textBox1.Text += "Total Time Taken = " + totalTime.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Which is giving the following result:

```
Time Taken 0 = 88
Time Taken 1 = 161
Time Taken 2 = 218
Time Taken 3 = 417
Time Taken 4 = 236
Time Taken 5 = 217
Time Taken 6 = 217
Time Taken 7 = 218
Time Taken 8 = 409
Time Taken 9 = 48
Total Time Taken = 257
```

I had expected the total time to be the sum of the individual times. Can anybody see why it is not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use TotalMilliseconds instead of Milliseconds and try your test again.  Your results aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, but like Nate says, what is the difference?

Comment: Milliseconds gets the current milliseconds *part* of the time, so 1.234 seconds would give 234.  TotalMilliseconds returns the whole time as milliseconds, so the above would be 1234.

Comment: Yes, `Milliseconds` is only the milliseconds fraction, it's not including the seconds, minutes, hours etc. that have passed. You can also use the `ElapsedMilliseconds` or `ElapsedTicks` properties.